# Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.9 ' was restored using .NetFramework, Version=v4.6.1, instead of the project target framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-assembly

I have an ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC project. I'm trying to add this dll `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.9` but I'm getting this below error. Please refer to this screenshot:
[image]

We are migrating from ASP.NET MVC 5 to ASP.NET Core 6.0 in Visual Studio 2022 (version 17.4.2)

I'm expecting `System.Web.Mvc` should be added to my project.

Thanks
Regards
Krishna

Comment: Why do you want to add this particular DLL? This is the **wrong version** - you need to get the .NET Core 6 version of this....

Answer (score 0):

You can generate some dummy ASP.NET MVC Core 6 project with VS2022, and take from its .csproj file, dependencies on MVC NuGet packages.
That way you are sure it has correct boilerplate code.